# Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Getting Null Point Exception on when I try to change `TextView` text to putExtra string from an `Intent`.

Here's my code:

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Login">


    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/receive"
            android:textSize="10sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity1.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun begin(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Key", "Value")

        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

activity2.kt

```
class Login : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val s: String = intent.getStringExtra("Key")
        println(s)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.receive).apply {
            text = s
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have to set text like below

```
class Login : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        val s: String = intent.getStringExtra("Key")
        println(s)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.receive).apply {
            text = s
        }
    }
}
```

Because you have to `setContentView` before you set value in `textView`. Other wise you get null while getting `textView`.